# How to call custom 404 page from view using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I want to call 404 page if anyone try to redirect wrong url.

i have create a 404 page in my view folder.

structure :

```
---View
  ---backend
    ---404.php
```

how can i call this 404.php page when wrong url call ?

Comment: in \application\config\routes.php add $route['404_override'] = 'controllernameof404';

Answer (score 0):

1) Create controller name "Notfound.php" in \application\controllers.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Notfound extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('404page');//load view
    }
}
```

2) in \application\config\routes.php add `$route['404_override'] = 'Notfound';`

Comment: i have create controller inside backend folder admin_controller and has a function show_404 and load a view but didn't work

Comment: But you can put controller in  "\application\controllers"

Comment: $this->load->view('backend/404page');

Comment: i did it and set $route['404_override'] = 'backend/admin_controller/show_404'; but didn't work

Comment: in function show_404 write this redirect(base_url() . "notfound"); for redirect to 404

Comment: create controller notfound.php in controller folder?

Comment: i am using query_string url format ,http://localhost/DemoTest/index?m=admin_controller&t=forgot_passwords&s=backend

Comment: No need to create function for 404. just follow my steps as define

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104721/discussion-between-manish-tiwari-and-meet).

Comment: Codeigniter 3 will not allow 404 controllers in sub folder.